# Get NSString value from app on jailbroken device

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsstring, jailbreak

Is it possible to get value of hard coded NSString from app on jailbroken device(with *reverse engineering* for example):

```
NSString *mySecretString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"stringValue"];
```

Can someone  get value "stringValue"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 'strings' utility from binutils on the app binary.
http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.18/binutils/strings.html

Example:

```
root@jailbroken-iPhone:~# strings HelloWorld
Hello, World!
root@jailbroken-iPhone:~# _
```

Comment: What if he does not know the name of the NSString?

Comment: Sorry...did not read well. 
I tried to run it on .app file(strings MyApp.app) and I got Invalid argument error.

Comment: @dule gotta run it on the *binary* itself :)